# Chrome-Extension: Load Background_JS only on request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome-extension in which I dynamly load JS-Files (depending on localstorage-settings)

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL("./setup/js/inner.js"), function() {
   DoInnerMagic();
});
```

But this only works if I add the inner.js to the content-scripts inside the manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts":
   [{
      "matches": ["https://mypage.com/*"],
      "js": [ "setup/js/inner.js" ]
   }]
```

But this causes the .js-file to be loaded even before I load it via code (I can see this in the dev-console from chrome)

What do I have to do to really load my file only when needed?

I need to do this from within a content-script, so chrome.tabs-functions would not work

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet doesn't make it clear how you're using the localStorage, or when it is read, but if I understand correctly, [event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) is most likely what you're looking for. Quoting the linked page:

> Event pages are very similar to background pages, with one important
>   difference: event pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the
>   event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing
>   memory and other system resources.

I used this just the other day to only load my .js when an event listener triggered, and it works great. Granted, the script I call is defined as a background script, e.g.:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["myScript.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```